# Android GridView of Images in Single Choice Mode only Selects Items with Keyboard in Emulator

Tags: android, kotlin

When deploying to device (Google Pixel 6) or emulator selecting an item does not highlight it, in single choice mode. Expecting color to set to teal_200 if selected. In emulator if I use arrow keys to browse, the items are selected. Confirmed with debugger setOnItemClickListener is getting hit. Have tried different things i.e. trying to set it checked. I can set the background color within this event of the clicked item, but then it remains even when next item is selected.
Android API 34 targeted.

**ConfigureProjectActivity.kt**

```
import android.graphics.Color
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import android.os.Bundle
import android.widget.EditText
import android.widget.GridView
import android.view.MotionEvent
class ConfigureProjectActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_configure_project)

        val projectTypes = mutableListOf<ProjectTypeAdapter.ProjectType>()

        for (i in 1..20) {
            val resourceName = "thumbnail_$i"
            val resId = resources.getIdentifier(resourceName, "drawable", packageName)
            projectTypes.add(ProjectTypeAdapter.ProjectType(resourceName, resId))
        }

        val adapter = ProjectTypeAdapter(this, projectTypes)
        val gridView: GridView = findViewById(R.id.projectTypeGridView)
        gridView.adapter = adapter

        gridView.setOnItemClickListener { parent, view, position, id ->
            val selectedProjectType = projectTypes[position]
            gridView.setSelection(position)
        }
    }

}
```

**ProjectTypeAdapter**

```
import android.content.Context
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.BaseAdapter
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.TextView

class ProjectTypeAdapter(private val context: Context, private val projectTypes: List<ProjectType>) : BaseAdapter() {

    override fun getCount(): Int = projectTypes.size

    override fun getItem(position: Int): ProjectType = projectTypes[position]

    override fun getItemId(position: Int): Long = position.toLong()

    override fun getView(position: Int, convertView: View?, parent: ViewGroup?): View {
        val projectType = getItem(position)
        val view: View =
            LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.grid_item_project_type, parent, false)

        val imageView: ImageView = view.findViewById(R.id.projectTypeImage)
       // val name: TextView = view.findViewById(R.id.projectTypeName)

        imageView.setImageResource(projectType.imageRes)
        //name.text = projectType.name

        return view
    }

    data class ProjectType(val name: String, val imageRes: Int)

}
```

**ActivityConfigureProject**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<EditText
    android:id="@+id/projectNameEditText"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:hint="Enter project name" />

<TextView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Select a project type"
    android:layout_marginTop="16dp"
    android:singleLine="true"/>

<GridView
    android:id="@+id/projectTypeGridView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:numColumns="2"
    android:verticalSpacing="5dp"
    android:horizontalSpacing="10dp"
    android:choiceMode="singleChoice"
    />
```

**grid_item_project_type**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:padding="8dp"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:background="@drawable/grid_item_selector">

    <!-- ImageView for the project type image -->
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/projectTypeImage"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="100dp"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        />

    <!-- TextView for the project type name -->
    <!--
    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/projectTypeName"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="1dp"
        android:textColor="@android:color/black"
        android:textSize="1sp"
        android:visibility="invisible"/>-->

</LinearLayout>
```

**grid_item_selector**

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <!-- Default color for the grid item -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/white" />
    <!-- Color when the grid item is selected -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/teal_200" android:state_selected="true" />
    <!-- Color when the grid item is pressed -->
    <item android:drawable="@color/teal_700" android:state_pressed="true" />
</selector>
```